# Utility classes in react that uses React-redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am learning react and stuck at a particular point. I want to have an utility js class that can be imported to most of the components. This utility class has to read the data from the store and then give the required information from the store.

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
class Test{
    constructor(){

    }

    getData(){
        // HOW TO GET THE DATA **HERE** ?
    }

}

function mapStateToProps(state){
    return { data: state.data};
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Test);
```

Is it ok to have the Test as a ReactComponent with render() returning a null and using it as a utility function in other components ?

Comment: Import the store and call `getState`.

Comment: Could you please give an example.. I am a newbie in React :(

Comment: You are actually creating class not component, a class is called component when you use react component base class

Answer (score 0):

You are adding extra complexity to your code using this class.
import `connect` in any component you need and add add:

```
function mapStateToProps(state){
    return { data: state.data};
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Test);
```

you can access the state using `props` in that component. also you can use selectors for your state object and use that selectors in your component.
you can use this pattern: [Redux Selector Pattern](https://gist.github.com/abhiaiyer91/aaf6e325cf7fc5fd5ebc70192a1fa170)